# How I can solve the read too much input problem in Python

Tags: python-3.x, math, input, user-input, grok

Here is my question:

You've devised a new twist on the traditional 'What number am I thinking of?' game to help your cousins learn their 7 times tables! Write a game that asks the user to guess the number you are thinking of. (For this game, the number will always be 42.)

The user is allowed 10 guesses, and makes a 'Mistake!' if they guess a number that isn't a multiple of 7. A user can make a maximum of one mistake, otherwise they lose the game. When the game is over, you should always print out That was fun.

Here is an example:

```
Guess a multiple of 7: 14
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 32
Mistake! That number isn't a multiple of 7.
Guess a multiple of 7: 28
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 86
Another mistake. Too bad.
That was fun.
```

Here is another example:

```
Guess a multiple of 7: 7
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 14
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 126
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 133
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 70
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 77
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 63
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 35
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 126
Nope!
Guess a multiple of 7: 77
Nope!
No guesses left!
That was fun.
```

If the user correctly enters 42, your program should print out You won! instead of Nope!, and then not ask for any more guesses. For example:

```
Guess a multiple of 7: 42
You won!
That was fun.
```

And now is my code:

```
guessCount = 0
mistakeMade = False

while True:
  guess = int(input("Guess a multiple of 7: "))
  if guess % 7 != 0:
    if mistakeMade:
      print("Another mistake. Too bad.")
      break
    else:
      print("Mistake! That number isn't a multiple of 7.")
      mistakeMade = True
  else:
    if guess == 42:
      print("You won!")
      break
    else:
      print("Nope!")
      guessCount += 1
      if guessCount == 10:
        print("No guesses left!")
        break
        
print("That was fun.")
```

I passed every check of Grok Learning except for this error:

> Testing a hidden case. Your submission attempted to read too much
> input! This occurred on line 5 of your submission.

I spent a lot of time thinking about it but it still hasn't solved the problem. Hope to receive help from everyone.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not incrementing the *guessCount* when a person is making a mistake. Try this out

```
wrongGuess = 0
for _ in range(10):
    guess = int(input("Guess a multiple of 7: "))
    if guess % 7 != 0:
        wrongGuess += 1
        if wrongGuess > 1:
            print("Another mistake. Too bad.")
            break
        else:
            print("Mistake! That number isn't a multiple of 7.")
            wrongGuess += 1
    else:
        if guess == 42:
          print("You won!")
          break
        else:
          print("Nope!")
else:
    print("No guesses left!")
        
print("That was fun.")
```

Note: For problems like this with finite count always try using *for loop*.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the incrementation and check for `guessCount` evertime, so remove it from the `if` condition.

---

[Edit] Old unrelated answer.

Maybe:

```
guess = int(input("Guess a multiple of 7: ").split()[0])
```

?